# Setting default option in my select form control when editing an object (Angular 15)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, frontend

When i create a reservation for a restaurant (the names will be in french sorry), i have this in my html file

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="nom">Restaurant :</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="nom" name="nom" [(ngModel)]="reservation.restaurant" required>
        <option [ngValue]="null">-- Select a restaurant --</option>
        <option *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurants" [ngValue]="restaurant">{{ restaurant.nom }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

and so i have "select a restaurant" displayed by default, but for the editing i try the same with

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="nom">Restaurant :</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="nom" name="nom" [(ngModel)]="reservation.restaurant" required>
        <option [ngValue]="reservation.restaurant">{{ reservation.restaurant.nom }}</option>
        <option *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurants" [ngValue]="restaurant">{{ restaurant.nom }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

but what i want to be the default option isn't displayed in the form, but in the list of the dropdown, so it appears twice in that list.

I tried to change a lot of things, but i cannot manage to have something displayed by default, like in the creation component. Here's my typescript component if it can help

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";
import {ReservationService} from "../../services/reservation.service";
import {ReservationModel} from "../../models/reservationModel";
import {RestaurantModel} from "../../models/restaurantModel";
import {RestaurantService} from "../../services/restaurant.service";
import {HoraireModel} from "../../models/horaireModel";
import {HorairesService} from "../../services/horaires.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edition-reservation',
  templateUrl: './edition-reservation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edition-reservation.component.css']
})
export class EditionReservationComponent implements OnInit {

  reservation!: ReservationModel
  restaurants: RestaurantModel[] = [];
  restaurants2: RestaurantModel[] = [];
  horaires: HoraireModel[] = [];
  index: number = 0;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private reservationService: ReservationService, private router: Router,
              private restaurantService: RestaurantService, private horaireService: HorairesService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getReservation();
    console.log(9,this.reservation);
  }

  private getReservation() {
    const id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.reservationService.getReservationById(id).then((reservation) => {
      this.reservation = reservation;
      this.getRestaurants();
      this.getHoraires();
      this.changeValues();
    });
  }

  getRestaurants() {
    this.restaurantService.getAll()
      .subscribe({
        next: (data)=>{
          this.restaurants = data;},
        error : ()=> {},
        complete: ()=>{this.restaurants2 = [...this.restaurants];
          if (this.reservation.restaurant) {
            for (let restaurant of this.restaurants2) {
              if (restaurant.id == this.reservation.restaurant?.id) {
                this.index = this.restaurants2.indexOf(restaurant);
                console.log(12,this.index);
              }
            }
          }
          this.restaurants2.splice(this.index, 1)
        }
      })
  }

  getHoraires(): void {
    this.horaireService.getAllHoraires()
      .subscribe({
        next: (data)=>{
          this.horaires = data;},
        error : ()=> {},
        complete: ()=>{console.log("complete",this.horaires)}
      })
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.reservationService.updateReservation(this.reservation).subscribe(() => {
      // this.router.navigate(['/reservations']).then((r) => console.log(r));
    });
  }

  private changeValues() {
    for (let restaurant of this.restaurants) {
      if (restaurant.id == this.reservation.restaurant?.id) {
        this.reservation.restaurant = restaurant;
      }
    }
    for (let horaire of this.horaires) {
      if (horaire.id == this.reservation.horaire?.id) {
        this.reservation.horaire = horaire;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and also my service since it is called several times

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {catchError, map, Observable, of, tap, throwError} from "rxjs";
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from "@angular/common/http";
import {ReservationModel} from "../models/reservationModel";
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ReservationService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private toastr: ToastrService) {
  }

  private reservationUrl = "http://localhost:8080/reservation/";

  private log(message: string) {
    console.log(`reservationService: ${message}`);
  }

  getAllReservations(): Observable<ReservationModel[]> {
    return this.http.get<ReservationModel[]>(this.reservationUrl + 'all')
      .pipe(tap(_ => this.log("fetched Reservations")),
        catchError(this.handleError<ReservationModel[]>('getAllReservations')));
  }

  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      let errorMsg: string;
      let statusCode: number;
      if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        // Server or connection error happened
        if (!navigator.onLine) {
          // Handle offline error
          errorMsg = 'No Internet Connection';
        } else {
          // Handle Http Error (error.status === 403, 404...)
          errorMsg = error.error instanceof ErrorEvent ? `Error: ${error.error.message}` : error.error;
          statusCode = error.status;
        }
      } else {
        // Handle other errors
        errorMsg = error.message || 'Server error';
      }

      // Log the error message
      console.error(`${operation} failed: ${errorMsg}`);

      // Return an empty result
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }


  deletereservationById(id: number): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.delete(this.reservationUrl + 'delete/' + id, {responseType: 'text'})
      .pipe(tap(_ => this.log("deleted reservation")),
        catchError(this.handleError<string>('deletereservationById')));
  }

  createReservation(reservation: ReservationModel): Observable<ReservationModel> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.reservationUrl + 'add', reservation, {responseType: 'json'})
      .pipe(
        tap(response => {
          if (response.status === 201) {
            this.toastr.success(response.message, '', {positionClass: 'toast-center'});
          } else {
            this.toastr.error(response.message, '', {positionClass: 'toast-center'});
          }
        }),
        map(response => response.reservation),
        catchError(error => {
          let errorMsg: string;
          if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
            // A client-side error occurred
            errorMsg = 'Une erreur est survenue lors de la création de la réservation.';
          } else {
            // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
            errorMsg = error.error.message;
          }
          this.toastr.error(errorMsg, '', {positionClass: 'toast-center'});
          return throwError(errorMsg);
        })
      );
  }

  getReservationById(id: number): Promise<ReservationModel> {
    return this.http.get<ReservationModel>(this.reservationUrl + 'find/' + id)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => this.log("fetched reservation")),
        catchError(this.handleError<ReservationModel>('getReservationById'))
      )
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        if (response && response.id) {
          return response as ReservationModel
        } else {
          throw new Error('Reservation not found');
        }
      });
  }

  updateReservation(reservation: ReservationModel): Observable<ReservationModel> {
    return this.http.put<any>(this.reservationUrl + 'update', reservation, {responseType: 'json'})
      .pipe(
        tap(response => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            this.toastr.success(response.message, '', {positionClass: 'toast-center'});
          } else {
            this.toastr.error(response.message, '', {positionClass: 'toast-center'});
          }
        }),
        map(response => response.reservation),
        catchError(error => {
          let errorMsg: string;
          if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
            // A client-side error occurred
            errorMsg = 'Une erreur est survenue lors de la mise à jour de la réservation.';
          } else {
            // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
            errorMsg = error.error.message;
          }
          this.toastr.error(errorMsg, '', {positionClass: 'toast-center'});
          return throwError(errorMsg);
        })
      );
  }
}
```

Anyway thank you for your answers, and sorry for the broken english.